# Python 3 Regex Last Match

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, python-3.x

How do I grab the `123` part of the following string using Python 3 regex module?

```
....XX (a lot of HTML characters)123
```

Here the `...` Part denotes a long string consisting of HTML characters, words and numbers.

The number `123` is a characteristic of `XX`. So if anybody could suggest a universal method in which `XX` can be any letters like `AA` or `AB`, it would be more helpful.

Side Note:
I thought of using Perl's `\G` operator by first identifying `XX` in the string and then identifying the first number appearing after `XX`. But it seems `\G` operator doesn't work in Python 3.

My code:

```
import re
source='abcd XX blah blah 123 more blah blah'
grade=str(input('Which grade?'))
#here the user inputs XX

match=re.search(grade,source)
match=re.search('\G\D+',source)
#Trying to use the \G operator to get the location of last match.Doesn't work.

match=re.search('\G\d+',source)
#Trying to get the next number after XX.
print(match.group())
```

Comment: Could you show your attempt so this problem can become more clear

Comment: your question is ambiguous,**incomplete**,effortless,and what have you tried..

Comment: What do you mean by "grab" it?  How about just `if '123' in text: print '123'`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802168/find-last-match-with-python-regular-expression

Comment: EDIT:Added a code snippet

Comment: `match.search(grade + ".*\(123\)", source)` Puts `123` in a capture group.

Comment: We don't know the number.
It's 123 only in this example.
In general it's a number from 0 to 900

Comment: You can specify starting position.    match = re.search(grade, source);
match = re.compile(r'\d+').search(source, match.end()); print(match.group())

Comment: Thanks @falsetru ! It's working. Could you explain what exactly is happening?

Comment: Compiled regular expression's search method accept optional pos parameter. http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search

Comment: Thanks once again :D @falsetru

Comment: Why bother using multiple expressions when you can just use `grade + r"\D*(\d+)"`?

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regex will match the string value `XX` which can be replaced with the user input. The regex will also require that the `XX` string be surrounded by white space or at the beginning of your sample text which prevents the accidental edge case where `XX` is found inside a word like `EXXON`.

`(?<=\s|^)\b(xx)\b\s.*?\s\b(\d+)\b(?=\s|$)`

[image]

## Code Example:

I don't know python well enough to offer a proper python example, so I'm including a PHP example to simply show how the regex would work and the captured groups

```
<?php
$sourcestring="EXXON abcd XX blah blah 123 more blah blah";
preg_match('/(?<=\s|^)\b(xx)\b\s.*?\s\b(\d+)\b(?=\s|$)/im',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
 
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => XX blah blah 123
    [1] => XX
    [2] => 123
)
```

If you need the actual string position, then in PHP that would look like

```
$position = strpos($sourcestring, $matches[0])
```

Comment: Just curious. What did you use to to generate the image?

Comment: @ Korylprince, I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.