# regex expression to match a pattern only if it preceded by one of the words in a list

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm new to regex in python. I tried finding answers over web from my problem but none of those works. I'm trying to replace the 's with "is" only if it is preceded by a singular pronoun. so word's like "he's", "it's", etc. are to be replaced by "he is", "it is".

What I tried was:

*line1 = "It's done. But there's some more you have to do. Gary's dog is in the precinct. Get it home. It's too far. There's rain"*

*re.sub("(?<=[it|that|here|there|he|she])'s",' is',line1,re.IGNORECASE)*

Answer I got:

"*It is done. But there is some more you have to do. Gary's dog is in the precinct. Get it home. It's too far. There's rain"*

It is doing what I want in first two sentences but not in later sentences. Can anyone point out my mistake and solution to it?

Comment: try using markdown to describe your `code` better.  it will help with readability

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.  First, you are confounding a regex character class with an alternation.  Your current lookbehind does not mean what you think:

```
(?<=[it|that|here|there|he|she])
```

This means that the previous *character* was one of the characters in the class, *not* one of the words.  It is the same as this:

```
[aehirst|]
```

But even fixing this won't work, because `re.sub` does not support variable width lookbehinds.  We can workaround this by capturing the previous term and then using it in the replacement:

```
re.sub("(it|that|here|there|he|she)'s", '\\1 is', line1, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

It is done. But there is some more you have to do. Gary's dog is in the precinct.
Get it home. It is too far. There is rain
```

### Demo

Comment: Doesn't run in python36 - `raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")`

Comment: Thanks.  Also explained here - [Python Regex Engine - “look-behind requires fixed-width pattern” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089922/python-regex-engine-look-behind-requires-fixed-width-pattern-error)

Comment: I ran with your suggestion, this is the result i got. I'm sure you ran before posting but why doesn't it work in my case

“It’s done. But \x01 is some more you have to do. Gary’s dog is in the precinct. Get it home. It’s too far. T\x01 is rain”

​

Comment: @ShreshthaKulkarni I had some minor typos in my answer, no doubt due to not testing my code.  Check the updated answer and demo where everything is working now.

Answer (score -1):

***Though i am not sure that it'll be very helpful but it does the trick:***

> Get rid of the `re.IGNORECASE` option.

```
>>> re.sub("(?<=[it|that|here|there|he|she])'s",' is',line1)
"It is done. But there is some more you have to do. Gary's dog is in the precinct. Get it home. It is too far. There is rain"
```

Comment: If your suggestion works, it is only by dumb luck.  The lookbehind `(<=[it|that...]` does _not_ match entire words, but only a class of characters.  Your answer should not be used, at least not as is.

Comment: but i wrote it in BOLD atop that my solution isn't very helpful for most cases but at-least **it works.**

Comment: Your pattern would replace the word `Gene's` with `Gene is`.  Again, coincidentally for the input give it works, but this should not be relied upon.

Comment: Yeah that's true.