# look-behind in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for the following pattern in a java code file: (var_name = "some text") following one condition: that such var_name is not a string literal itself, being enclosed within quotations.
In other words, the word "var_name" has to be followed by "=" sign followed by a string literal enclosed within quotations.

For example:

1. valid pattern:`var_name = "  ";`   it should be a pattern match here
2. valid pattern: `another_var = "  "; var_name = "  "` it should also be a pattern match here
3. invalid pattern: `another_var = "  var_name = "` it should not be a pattern match here
4. **valid** pattern: `another_var = "  var_name = "; var_name = "  "` it should be a pattern match here as well.

What I have come up with :
`r"(?<!\".+)\s*var_name\s*=\s*[\'|\"].+[\'|\"]\s*"`

However, re in python requires look-behind to have fixed-width pattern, and  even this pattern doesn't find a match for the 4th example here..

So, first, If we are to modify this regex to at least find a match for the first 3 examples, how it would be like?

And second, what do you suggest for the 4th example?

I think a close solution to what I need is in the following link, but I wasn't able to modify it for this use case.
[Python Regex Engine - "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089922/python-regex-engine-look-behind-requires-fixed-width-pattern-error)

Comment: Your current pattern does not find a match in `another_var = "  "; var_name = "  "`

Comment: yes, but I needed to at least have a valid match for the first 3 examples..

Comment: You are most probably heading a blind alley, parsing arbitrary Java code files with a single regex is not going to work in the end. Use a dedicated paraser, or build your own.

Comment: Ok, if I ignore the 4th example for now. Do you suggest a workaround to find matches for the first 3 examples without using a parser?

Comment: No, and I am sure a lookbehind is not going to help much here.

Answer (score -1):

Is it that what you were looking for? I don't know if I did understand everything

```
\bvar_name\b\s*=\s*("|')\s*("|')
```