# python3 sqlite and regex query

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

I use python3 to search an exact word in a sqlite3 database. When I do it with SQLite database browser it works perfectly. But when I do it with python3, it throws:
sqlite3.OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception. (I will use this code for an app to search in a treeview)

Here is the code:

```
import sqlite3
import re


def regexp(expr, item):
    reg = re.compile(expr)
    return reg.search(item) is not None
conn = sqlite3.connect('/database.db')
conn.create_function("REGEXP", 2, regexp)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP ?',['(?i)(?<=\s|^|\W)word(?=\s|$|\W)'])
data=cursor.fetchall()
print(data)
```

I updated my code as:

```
import sqlite3
import re
def regexp
def regexp(expr, item):
    try:
        pattern = re.compile(expr, re.I)

        return re.search(pattern, str) is not None
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
conn.create_function("regexp", 2, regexp)
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute(r'SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP ?',[r'(?i)(?<=\s|^|\W)word(?=\s|$|\W)'])
    data=cursor.fetchall()
    print(data)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

And it throws :
look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: Did you try to write first parameter in create_function in lowercase as "regex" ?

Comment: yes and it does not work... See my edit pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?i)(?<=\s|^|\W)word(?=\s|$|\W)` pattern contains a lookbehind with alternatives, two of which match a single-char pattern and one of them matches no char (`^` only asserts the position at the start of string).

The problem is that [Python `re` does not support lookbehinds of non-fixed length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617321/3832970). Let's try to refactor the regex:

- `(?i)(?<=[\s\W]|^)word(?=[\s\W]|$)`: Look how single-char matching patterns are grouped with the help of a character class. We now clearly see that `[\s\W]` can be re-written as `\W` because `\W` matches whitespaces. So, the regex can look like
- `(?i)(?<=\W|^)word(?=\W|$)`: Better, but it is still not what we need, the alternatives do not match the same amount of chars. However, at this point I can clearly see you want to match a `word` in between non-word chars or start/end of string.

So, you can use

```py
(?i)(?<!\w)word(?!\w)
```

with `(?<!\w)` [*negative* lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and `(?!\w)` *negative* lookahead both containing a single `\w` (no more alternation operator necessary!), which is basically

```py
(?i)\bword\b
```

with mere [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (in Python code, `r'(?i)\bword\b'`).

**However**, the pattern variant with the lookarounds can be prefereble in cases the `word` is a variable, when you use it like

```py
fr'(?i)(?<!\w){re.escape(word)}(?!\w)'
```

As far as the code is concerned, you have a typo in the `regexp` method: `str` cannot be used as the input argument to `re.search`. You can fix it by using

```py
def regexp(expr, item):
    try:
        return re.search(expr, item, re.I) is not None
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

See demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! Now after I replace this, it throws me a new error "expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: Ok.. but how to solve this problem?? this is related to python because the query works on sqlite browser

Comment: @Béa See updated code for `regexp` method.

Comment: Thank u..But I still receive "expected string or bytes-like object" ... In SQLte the column is a TEXT type so I don't understand

Comment: I write the same code but it gives me a lot of expected string or bytes-like object errors ...

Comment: @Béa That means the `item` is not of type string. Try `return re.search(expr, str(item), re.I) is not None`

Comment: Thank you soo soo much ! it works !! So happy