# Regex match words that are by their own or surrounded by underscores

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to match the word `int` that's either by its own or it's surrounded by underscores (`_`).

```py
int  # match
_int_  # match
__int__  # match
some_int  # match
int_var  # match
integration  # doesn't match
mint  # doesn't match
```

This is what I've been trying, but it only matches the second case above

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=[\W_])int(?=[\W_])")
```

How should I go about doing this?
Thanks everyone

Comment: KISS `(?<=[\W_])int(?=[\W_])|^int$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the *double negation* logic in this case:

```py
(?<![^\W_])int(?![^\W_])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z8TESO/1).

The `(?<![^\W_])` lookbehind matches a location that is not immediately preceded with any char other than a non-word and `_` char. It means, there must be a start of string position or any non-word char other than `_` immediately on the left.

The `(?![^\W_])` lookahead matches a location that is not immediately followed with any char other than a non-word and `_` char. It means, there must be an end of string position or any non-word char other than `_` immediately on the right.

In **your regex**, the `(?<=[\W_])` positive lookebehind you used *requires* a non-word or `_` immediately on the left and `(?=[\W_])` positive lookahead requires a non-word or an underscore char immediately on the right. Hence, *these lookarounds are not allowing matches at the start or end of string*.

**NOTE**: As you are using Python `re`, you cannot simply add a `^|` alternative to your lookbehind, because Python `re` [does not allow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617321/3832970) lookbehinds with non-fixed-width patterns. `(?<=[\W_]|^)int(?=[\W_]|$)` will work in PHP/PCRE, Java, Ruby/Onigmo, but won't work in Python `re`. That is why double negation way is the only way here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please explain why this works and my version doesn't?