# Python Regex: Match start of line, or semi-colon, or start of string, none capturing group

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a Python regex that matches either:

1. The start of the string
2. The start of a line
3. Or a semi colon

Up to here it must be a none consuming of the string.
Once the above is found, then it looks for optional whitespace and then the word `import` (which is captured).

The regex (with the mutline and global flags (mg)):

```
(?<=^|;)\s*(import)
```

Fails because a look behind must be fixed width in python:

```
import sadfsda; import asdf sdaf 
import asdfas dfasdf
```

Note: [^] does answer the question, because how do you specify the a fixed width look behind that matches my requirements. This was just one of the many attempts that didnt work.

Comment: But in this case, all you want is `(?<![^;])\s*(import)`. Besides, are you replacing? Splitting? Removing?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, good answer, but doesnt match the import on the 2nd line, i.e. the 3rd import (even with multiline flagged)

Comment: @run_the_race cant you loop it line by line and use Wiktors regex?

Comment: @user56700, unfortunately I can't, the regex is feed into Django's manifest storage handler, and it processes it.

Comment: I tweaked @WiktorStribiżew 's answer, `(?<![^;\n])\s*(import)` seems to do the trick`

Comment: It is because negated character classes match newlines if `\n` is not part of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<![^;\n])\s*(import)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IM1tHK/1). *Details*:

- `(?<![^;\n])` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a `;` and a newline (LF, line feed) char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(import)` - Group 1: `import` string.

The `\n` line feed matching pattern is necessary since negated character classes match newlines if `\n` is not part of the class, so add it to the negated character class whenever you want to match positions at the start of any line with a negative lookbehind like this.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/66TRYd):

```py
import re
s='''import sadfsda; import asdf sdaf 
import asdfas dfasdf'''
rx = r'(?<![^;\n])\s*(import)'
print( re.sub(rx, r'{{\g<0>}}', s) )
```

Output:

```
{{import}} sadfsda;{{ import}} asdf sdaf 
{{import}} asdfas dfasdf
```