# Python "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" - Regular Expression Error

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex, it matches a certain word if a list of word are not found:

`(?<![Yy]ellow |[Bb]lue |[Rr]ed |[Pp]urple |[Bb]lack )[Cc]olor`

It works, but I get the Regex Expression Error: "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern".
I do not have access to the python code.
I tried delimiting by `(?:^` and `|$)` as I saw in a similar question but it didn't work.
I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617321/16958187) that I think solves the problem but I don't understand how to make it work in my case.

Test [HERE](https://regexr.com/6v84o)

```
Dark Color          #match
light color         #match
Blue Color
red color
that is a blue color and theme
opaque color        #match
purple color
```

Comment: See *Negative lookbehinds can be just concatenated (e.g. `(?<!^|,)"(?!,|$)` should look like `(?<!^)(?<!,)"(?!,|$))`.* in the [answer you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617321/16958187).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split up the alternatives in the lookbehind with separated loopbehind assertions if you want a match only.

If you don't want partial word matches, you can start with a word boundary `\b`

```
\b(?<![Yy]ellow )(?<![Bb]lue )(?<![Rr]ed )(?<![Pp]urple )(?<![Bb]lack )[Cc]olor
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y1Q1WV/1).

As suggested by @
[bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble) you can prevent the negative lookaheads from firing by first asserting or matching that the next character is a `C` or `c` char.

```
\b(?=[Cc])(?<![Yy]ellow )(?<![Bb]lue )(?<![Rr]ed )(?<![Pp]urple )(?<![Bb]lack ).olor
```

See a [regex demo asserting](https://regex101.com/r/tFimzm/1) or a regex demo [matching](https://regex101.com/r/EsnoSD/1) the first character..

---

If you have no control over the Python code, you might check if matching what you don't want and returning a capture group for what you do want also works:

```
\b(?:[Yy]ellow |[Bb]lue |[Rr]ed |[Pp]urple |[Bb]lack )[Cc]olor|([Cc]olor)
```

See a third [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ntCtBh/1).

Comment: Sidenote @cy614 that it will be more efficient if a word boundary can be [`used at start`](https://regex101.com/r/swafl8/1). If this a large text and there are many lookbehinds, the starting point can be further defined, eg something like [`\b(?=[Cc])`(?<!many lookbehinds)`.olor`](https://regex101.com/r/B6HIj6/1) but this was not asked. :)

Comment: @bobblebubble Ow that is very smart and much more performant indeed.

Comment: @bobblebubble Is it ok if I add that last pattern from you comment to the answer? You can always post it yourself :-)

Comment: Sure if you like, I'd be happy! To mention that I had tested that with Python. In PCRE2 at least it seems such modification would not make much difference (even a bit slower).

Answer (score 2):

I would get around the fixed width lookbehind problem by instead phrasing your regex using a negative *lookahead*, which doesn't have this limitation:

```
\b(?!yellow|blue|red|purple|black)\w+ color\b
```

Here is a working Python script:

```py
inp = """Dark Color
light color
Blue Color
red color
that is a blue color and theme
opaque color
purple color"""

matches = re.findall(r'\b(?!yellow|blue|red|purple|black)\w+ color\b', inp, flags=re.I)
print(matches)  # ['Dark Color', 'light color', 'opaque color']
```