# Regexp to find caret preceding integers not working

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace this `[^19) Jones, Owen.` with this `[^19] Jones, Owen.` using this regexp statement:

```py
re.sub(r'(?<=\[\^[0-9])(\) )','] ', text)
```

But no replacement occurs and I'm unable to find the issue. Please help.

Comment: Remove the space, or use `re.X` option, `re.sub(r'(?<=\[\^[0-9])(\) )','] ', text, flags=re.X)`. There must be no space after `)`. Else, your solution works.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: It [does work](https://regex101.com/r/V6sGZM/2). Show your code, only your code might fail here. Also, what error do you get?

Comment: Here's exactly what I'm using 
html = re.sub(r'(?<=\[\^[0-9])(\))',']', html, flags=re.X)

And the string that I want to replace is [^19) Jones, Owen. with this [^19] Jones, Owen.

Comment: Then you need `re.sub(r'(\[\^\d+)\) ', r'\1] ', text)`

Comment: Put those details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```py
re.sub(r'(\[\^\d+)\) ', r'\1] ', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V6sGZM/3).

*Details*:

- `(\[\^\d+)` - Group 1 (whose value is referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): `[^` and one or more digits
- `\)`  - a `)`  string.

Note you cannot use a lookbehind here, since `\d+` matches a non-fixed amount of digits, and [Python `re` lookbehind requires fixed-width patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20089922/3832970).

Comment: Okay. so the problem was with the lookahead '?<=' that I was using. Thanks for the explanation.