# How to search for the last occurrence of a regular expression in a string in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

In python, I can easily search for the first occurrence of a regex within a string like this:

```
import re
re.search("pattern", "target_text")
```

Now I need to find the last occurrence of the regex in a string, this doesn't seems to be supported by `re` module.

I can reverse the string to "search for the first occurrence", but I also need to reverse the regex, which is a much harder problem.

I can also iterate to find all occurrences from left to right, and just keep the last one, but that looks awkward.

Is there a smart way to find the rightmost occurrence?

Comment: Depending on what you have, you could modify the regex to *find the first instance of the string just before the end of the string*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find last match with python regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802168/find-last-match-with-python-regular-expression)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One approach is to prefix the regex with `(?s:.*)` and force the engine to try matching at the furthest position and gradually backing off:

```
re.search("(?s:.*)pattern", "target_text")
```

Do note that the result of this method may differ from `re.findall("pattern", "target_text")[-1]`, since the `findall` method searches for **non-overlapping** matches, and not all substrings which can be matched are included in the result.

For example, executing the regex `a.a` on `abaca`, `findall` would return `aba` as the only match and select it as the last match, while the code above will return `aca` as the match.

---

Yet another alternative is to use [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package, which supports `REVERSE` matching mode.

The result would be more or less the same as the method with `(?s:.*)` in `re` package as described above. However, since I haven't tried the package myself, it's not clear how backreference works in `REVERSE` mode - the pattern might require modification in such cases.

Comment: `findall` with `lookahead with a group` will get you overlapping matches

Comment: @vks: If you mean `(?=pattern)` then yes, but I guess it would be less efficient when there are many matches. The `pattern` has to be fully executed per match found.

Comment: It would have been nice to get an explanation for `(?s:.*)` for those who are not too familiar with regex. If someone is as confused as I was: `(?:)` is a non-capturing group, i.e. the content will not be present in the captured result. The `s` modifier changes the behavior of the dot `.` to capture also newline characters. So `(?s:.*)` matches literally everything (including empty string) but will not be in the result. Due to the greedy nature of regex it first matches as much as it can (everything) and then reduces the length of the group so the match ends in `pattern`. Great answer though!

Comment: In addition: due to the way non-capturing groups work in python, to get the desired match, one needs to group the pattern actually  `re.search("(?s:.*)(pattern)", "target_text").group(1)`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703029/why-isnt-the-regular-expressions-non-capturing-group-working

Comment: Check the performance of the `(?s:.*)` method vs re.findall() for any sizeable target text.  MUCH SLOWER when a pattern is not found.

Answer (score 15):

```
import re
re.search("pattern(?!.*pattern)", "target_text")
```

or

```
import re
re.findall("pattern", "target_text")[-1]
```

You can use these 2 approaches.

If you want `positions` use

```
x="abc abc abc"
print [(i.start(),i.end(),i.group()) for i in re.finditer(r"abc",x)][-1]
```

Comment: `findall` returns a list of strings without position info, which is what I need. The first solution is smart, but what if the regex is not modifiable (suppose `pattern` is provided as a regex object), is there still a way?

Comment: Just checked that this solution has a quadratic complexity, @nhahtdh answer is linear from the end, thus very fast if searched expression is near the end.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use split. For example if you wanted to get the last group after ':' in this sample string:

```
mystr = 'dafdsaf:ewrewre:cvdsfad:ewrerae'
':'.join(mystr.split(':')[-1:])
```

Comment: Not the best solution, but +1 :) It solved another simple issue I had ;)